# How to filter log4j logs besides log levels?

Tags: java, log4j

I need to filter some `log.info` console statements meant for prod maven profile, while I'm in dev.

For example:
log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = INFO,console,file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %-5X{username} %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass{

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

and then in some place we use `log.info` writing many info for production. I want to remove this info while developing. Maybe for such production case I could use different logger, turning his output on/off in properties (depending on maven profile).

Thanks

Comment: Example?  There are many approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use differnt logger and configure log4j to use differnt log levels for them. If you do not want some of them just set `NONE` as log level.